# Print JSON object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have some JSON data looking like this:

```
"Extras": {
  "T01": "Value 1",
  "T02": "Value 2",
  "T03": "Value 3",
  // etc.
}
```

I need each of these values in a list, and so I've tried this:

```
$.each(data.result, function(i){
  $("#result").append('<li>'+data.result.Extras[]+'</li>');
});
```

Which obviously doesn't work, I just can't seem to figure out what to do. I've tried `data.result.Extras` with no luck (as I just get `[object][Object]`).

Any ideas what I can do to get all of the values in a list? Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to tick the answer as the correct one though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating the `data.result`, I believe you need to iterate the `Extras`.

```
$.each(data.result.Extras, function(k, v){
  $("#result").append('<li>'+v+'</li>');
});
```

Note: In the above function `k` is key and `v` is value in the object `Extras`. For ex: For the first iterate `k` would be `T01` and `v` would be `Value 1`.

The above should produce and output of

```
<ul id="result">
   <li>Value 1</li>
   <li>Value 2</li>
   <li>Value 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using eval method to convert JSON string, it will give you an obj of JSON, which you can use to get values of each property of JSON String like 'TO1' ,'TO2'

for e.g

```
var jsonstr = '"Extras": { "T01": "Value 1", "T02": "Value 2", "T03": "Value 3"}';
var obj = eval(jsonstr);
alert(obj.TO1);
```